# Smart, dynamic, automatic placement of figures in Beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, positioning

I recently switched to LaTex for document preparation. I've been using Beamer in the last few weeks. While I can make the slides look good, it requires many rounds of trial and error processes to have an acceptable layout. The energy and time involved is really discouraging.

Particularly, I feel that placing figures in a frame can be a pain. Especially when I try to include more than one column or more than one figure. I had to adjust the size of the figure (percentage of \textwidth, or \textheight) many times in order to place them nicely. I wonder if there is a way to automate the process. Say, if I have a figure and a bullet list, when I use that magic (a macro/snippet), the column widths for the figure and the bullet list will be automatically determined.

Such a method may not exist, please share your thoughts on how to use LaTex more efficiently to prepare slid shows.

Thank you!

Comment: in a latex itemize list the width available is `\linewidth` what did you try? If you show no code it is hard for anyone to suggest improvements.

Comment: Maybe the package [subcaption](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) is of interest to you. The package description does not mention your problem explicitely, but the [manual](https://packages.oth-regensburg.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) explains how to use the package's subfigure environment in chapter 3.